# Bash Scripting - nohup, but then leave process running?

Tags: php, bash, nohup

I've got a PHP script running a bunch of commands to execute bash scripts, via system() with nohup.

The command line to call sh looks like:-

```
system('nohup /home/me/script.sh %s %d %d 2>&1 > %s');
```

I want the .sh script to be set running, and then leave it and return to my continue my PHP script. However, what is happening, is it's being started and then holding to get a response/complete before proceeding.

How can I set it running and then 'hang up' or leave it?

Answer (score 3):

Just append an ampersand `&` in the end like this:

```
system('nohup /home/me/script.sh %s %d %d 2>&1 > %s &');
```

This will execute the shell script in a separate sub process and return immediately to php.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I had actually tried this. Admittedly, I've seen this work in the past. But, for some reason it just doesn't seem to move on. Is it dependent on anything to do with the program you're running. I'm setting ffmpeg going in this script, then returning to set another one going.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to run this shell script after you exit PHP then it is suggested to run program in a new session using **setsid**. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setsid.php for example or use setsid program

Comment: @waxical Was this the answer you were looking for?